# Wrong facebook hash after reinstall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm having an odd problem.

I'm trying to integrate facebook login into my app using their sdk. I was able to make the login work and everything went smoothly. Now we wish to publish the product so i signed the apk and added the release keyhash to facebook using openssl command.

To properly test everythnig i removed the app from the device and cleared it from my facebook account as a user.
After installing the app i was indeed able to login and everything is working. However after uninstalling the app again (and this time not clearing the app from facebook account) and installing it again i receive a hash key mismatch. It made no sense to me since im using the same signed apk.

Also note that this odd thing only happening if the native facebook app is installed on the device.

Have anyone encountered such a problem before ? i've been wrestling with this for a while

Comment: Are you generating hash key via code?

Comment: @VivekMishra im generating the code using openssl 9.8k in commandline using : keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but I don't have may reputation for comment but same happened with me before.
When we create release apk it will generate new hash key. For this you can run the release mode apk from android studio and write the key from code to console and then add this key too to Facebook account. To generate key code is given below:

//Get key hash for the facebook account

```
 try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your package name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Comment: This has worked for me, just as a side note after you use this to get the hash dont forget to comment out the log to avoid exposing your secret hash